# Example of windowed npapi-plugin

Tags: windows, plugins, npapi, windowed

Where can I find the example of windowed npapi-plugin or detailed documentation (for Windows)?

Answer (score 2):

There is some older code in the [Seamonkey sources](http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/modules/plugin/samples/npruntime/) that does simple drawing.
Mozillas [test plugin](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/plugins/test/testplugin/) is not as straight-forward, but definitely up-to-date.

Keep in mind though that [window-less plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Basics#Windowed%20and%20Windowless%20Plug-ins) are preferrable due to most browsers running the plugins out-of-process as well as integration into their layering-/drawing-mechanisms being better.

Also, take a look at wether [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/) fits your project - it is a plugin-framework that already does much of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks. Is Flash a windowed or window-less plugin?

Comment: It depends on the wmode of the Flash instance; it can operate in either mode.

Comment: @smorgan: Thanks, i somehow missed this comment.

Comment: Thanks. Windowed plugin can't be transparent?